# Qual è il significato di "cudruzzo"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto:

> Prendete il sofrolio, toglietegli le foglie e il **cudruzzo**, fatene quattro parti, poi lessatelo.

La mia domanda è sul significato del termine "cudruzzo", che non ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Non so se si tratti di una parola di origine dialettale. A proposito, "sofrolio" è un vocabolo inventato da Benni per questo romanzo: si tratta di un'erba segreta che ha una cuoca chiamata Sofronia.

Comment: Pqcv, non c'è neanche nel *Dizionario etimologico dei dialetti italiani* di Cortelazzo e Marcato.

Comment: Considerando il resto del testo e del linguaggio usato, è possibile che sia anche questa una parola inventata? Dopotutto, se il “sofrolio” è un termine di fantasia, potrebbe esserlo anche una sua parte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

«Cudruzzo» è un termine dialettale bolognese, indica la parte più in alto fra le natiche.

Lascio a te l'interpretazione metaforica nel riferimento all'erba.

Comment: P.S. Alcuni riferimenti puoi trovarli online con una ricerca di [questo tipo](https://www.google.it/search?q="cudruzzo"+-"monte+cudruzzo")

Comment: Grazie della risposta e benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 2):

In aggiunta alla spiegazione di @horcrux è interessante questo passaggio trovato in un articolo tratto dal [Corriere di Bologna](http://www.pressreader.com/italy/corriere-di-bologna/20101224/281487862777905) in cui c'è la spiegazione del termine:

> Un buco nell'acqua la bolognesità, e dopo di lei una frana, un
>   cascatone sul "**cudruzzo**" - ***che sarebbe poi lì fra le natiche dove ai
>   nostri antenati spuntava la coda*** - che ci ha rintronato tutti.